# iPhone 3GS and iOS 5 don't sync

Tags: data-synchronization, ios, iphone

After updating my iPhone 3GS to iOS 5.0.1 from 4.3 on Sunday Evening, and letting it finish syncing, I tried playing my music in the morning. I thought it was great that it held the last song I was playing, but it never actually played it. I hit Play, the play logo appears on the status bar. The Pause button switches back to Play on the iPod Controls screen. I can hit Next or Previous, and it does the same thing. One about 1 out of every 20 songs, it will play a song, although all the tags are matched up to a different song.

I tried Resyncing, with a cable and over Wifi for the past couple of nights, but the same thing keeps happening. I am running iTunes 10.5.1 on a MacBook Pro with OSX 10.6.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing all the songs from the device and just allowing a handful to sync?

Sometimes the tracking database gets in a bad state and cleaning things out lets you know it's safe to sync the whole load again.

Comment: I will try that tonight when I get home

Comment: That has worked. I can listen to my music now

Answer (score 1):

Simply restore your iPhone.

Unfortunately, corruption and bugs do sometimes happen (my 3GS had these symptoms once under iOS 4). Luckily, Apple made restoring painless thanks to automatic backups (unless you disabled them, which would be problematic).

So really, don't waste time struggling and simply restore, it will take 20-40 minutes depending on the capacity and usage of your iPhone, then you'll be up and running again :)

Comment: Takes me an hour and a half with a USB cable to restore. I'm waiting for the wifi sync to finish first then illtry this

Comment: I'm sure this would work, but I just finished the wifi sync after taking bmike's advice, and it worked so I can't test yours. I still +1'd it for you though since it probably would work

Comment: Actually a restore can place the same corrupt iTunes database file on the device after the restore. It could fix some of the potential causes of Luke's issue, but certainly won't fix some causes of this issue. The steps I outlined were more surgical at attacking the specific issue. A restore is good general advice, just not the best for this specific situation.

Comment: Of course, restoring a corrupt backup won't correct the problem. However, considering how long it usually takes to pinpoint a problem with the syncing process, I've ended up usually advising restore as a quicker solution. In the worst case, you'll have to do the research part afterwards. Anyway, your more precise solution was elected, and I am glad it was in this case  :)